# Передача параметра через программу в MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi

Есть таблица в которую записываются данные через программу. При редактировании записи срабатывает триггер AFTER UPDATE, который вставляет старые значения записи в архивную таблицу. В архивной таблицу у меня имеется поле - id пользователя, отредактировавшего запись. Как мне через программу передать id пользователя в триггер?

Comment: *В архивной таблицу у меня имеется поле - id пользователя, отредактировавшего запись.* Какой именно ID, откуда? Во всей этой каше у пользователя разных ID в разных точках выполнения аки блох на собаке.

Comment: @Akina, ID берётся из таблицы users и хранится в глобальной переменной при успешной авторизации

Comment: Соответственно на момент логирования это внешний параметр. И его следует передавать в запрос явным образом. Например, добавлением в источник данных запроса подзапроса, который копирует значение в UDV. Либо даже делать это в доп. команде в свойствах соединения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант 1. Добавить в вашу таблицу поле `user_id`, заполнять его при обновлении записи в программе, а в триггере получать через `NEW.user_id`

Вариант 2. Создать в базе [временную таблицу](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html) (можно даже на движке `MEMORY`), по старту программы записать туда ID пользователя, а в триггере читать из этой таблицы